# How to set shape in image with clip-path

Tags: html, css, clip-path

Is it possible to set image in same shape with `clip-path` css.

**Original Image**

[image]

**Expected image with css**

[image]

Comment: It looks as though the shape you want can be created with clip-path (ie the path defined) but for complex shapes it's worth looking at mask-image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need clip-path or mask. A skew transformation with border-radius can do it:

```css
.box {
  margin:50px;
  border-radius:80px 0;
  height:300px;
  background:red;
  position:relative;
  background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYeuk.jpg) center/cover;
  transform:skewY(-7deg);
  transform-origin:right;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.box::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  background:inherit;
  top:-20%;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:-20%;
  transform:skewY(7deg);
}

body {
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```