# Background gradient advanced in CSS

Tags: css, background, gradient

I need to do that type of things in css. You guys have any ideas about how to do it ?
For the gradient no problem, but the effects of rounding in some areas I don't know at all.

[blue background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29H4E.jpg) ;
[blue background again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7S4Fp.png)

Thanks to you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64498483/8620333 (replace the image with your gradient)

Answer (score -1):

You could use css `clip-path` or `mask` or use a svg as background instead of a css gradient in order to get the shape you need.